# What javascript libraries would help automate a interface from json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, knockout.js, jsrender

Problem: Imagine we have a workflow engine that was used for various infrastructure tasks within an environment.  Each workflow has its own directory with property files which are used by the workflow engine.  Instead of a using separate user interfaces we want to have a common UI that can adopt to whichever flow is selected.

Is there a javascript library that would be best to automate the collection of user input based on a json template?

For example if I know X flow requires 3 inputs I can simply define them in a json property file and our universal UI, using a magic javascript library, would simplify the creation of the UI.  Ideally if we had common inputs that were used across workflows they could be defined in a global configuration file and reused/referenced by some of the workflow specific property files.

I looked at the following but could use some direction:
-JsRender/JsViews
-Knockout.js
-Angular.js

Comment: Looks like a duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042086/javascript-to-generate-render-dynamic-html-form-from-json-or-similar-data
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905849/generating-html-forms-from-json-or-xml-feed-using-jquery